# Where is Product ID value of internet explorer located?

Tags: windows-7, browser, windows-explorer, internet-explorer-11

At **About Internet Explorer** menu can see several parameters - version,update version and Product ID. All values can be found in registry HLKM\software\microsoft\internet explorer\registration, except Product ID.
In tree presents ProductID binary entry, but it contains different information.

Where is Product ID value of internet explorer located?

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way but: What is your objective?  Is it just for the sake of knowing where it is?  If you're trying to solve a specific problem, please advise.

Comment: I suspect that the registry value does contain this information but in encoded form. Don't expect to see this documented anywhere. There is no point to encoding if you tell everybody how it works.

Answer (score 0):

At last i found. Location of this string is ieframe.dll (windows\system32\ and windows\syswow64). Open file in Hex editor and look for string in unicode.